# Footer Resize Issue

Tags: html, css, footer

The issue I am having is when the browser is re-size, the content in the footer does stack on each other correctly. However, their is a point when the footer is re-sizing that it gets funky. I am new to this and would like to know if their is a better approach. Thank you and I will attach the jsfiddle file to view the issue: 
http://jsfiddle.net/robontrix/h21fyywn/#&togetherjs=cjr35cIPDP

HTML Footer

```
 <footer>
    <div id="footer-right">
        <ul>
            <li>ABOUT US</li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FAQ's</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Site Map</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>SUPPORT OUR CAUSE</li>
            <li><a href="">Donate</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Volunteer</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Fundraising Events</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>FOLLOW US</li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Facebook"><img src="img/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
                <a href="#Instagram"><img src="img/instagram-icon.png" alt="Instagram Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
                <a href="#Twitter"><img src="img/twitter-icon.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"/></a>
                <a href="#Pinterest"><img src="img/pinterest-icon.png" alt="Pinterest Logo" class="social-icon"/></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-left">
        <p id="footer-slogan">BREAK THE <strong>SILENCE</strong> <br>AND <strong>CYCLE</strong>    OF ABUSE</p>
        <p id="copyright">Copyright&copy; 2014 International Child Advocacy Network</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS Footer

```
/**********************
FOOTER
**********************/
footer {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
max-width:950px;
background-color:#434a54;
font-size:0.75em;
clear:both;
color:#e6e9ed; overflow:auto;
margin: 0 auto;
padding:5px;
}
footer h3{
padding-left: .9em;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
footer ul {
display:inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
}
footer ul li{
list-style:none;
text-decoration:none;
margin-left: 1em;
}
footer ul li a{
color:#e6e9ed;
text-decoration:none;
}

footer a:hover {
color:#FFFFFF; /*Change hover color to make it more prominent*/
}


/**********************
RIGHT SIDE OF FOOTER - Contains links and social media icons
**********************/
#footer-right {
float:right;
margin-right:15px;
}

#footer-right li:nth-child(1) { /*Styles footer headers*/
font-weight:bold;
font-size:1.2em;
padding-bottom:4px;
}

.social-icon {
display:inline-block;
width:24px;
height:24px;
margin-bottom:22.7px; /*controls height of "follow us" in footer*/
padding:1px;
border-radius: 20%;
}

/**********************
LEFT SIDE OF FOOTER - Contains copyright and slogan
**********************/
#footer-left {  
float:left;
padding-left: 2em;
text-align:left;
font-size: 1.35em;
display:inline-block;
line-height: 1.5em;
}

#footer-slogan {
font-family: 'Georgia', 'Droid Serif', sans-serif;
}

#copyright{
font-size: .75em;
text-align:left;
margin-top: 5px; 
display:inline-block;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by funky?  at about how many pixel must the screen be to see this funkiness?

Comment: I am attaching a screen shot of the issue: http://postimg.org/image/o99m83nk3/  As you can, there is a space on top of "Break the Silence" and underneath that the Copyright. I would like "About Us", "Follow Us" and so on to move to the left, where the space resides. Is this possible and thank you for asking what I mean. I hope my explanation clarifies the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is a space is because your footer-right is doing a "float:right;".   However, there is not enough space when there are less than around 888px, so footer-left is being pushed down, and footer-right occupies the right side of whatever space there is.

All you need is to employ css media queries for responsive design.  In your particular case, you can do something like:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 888px) {
        #footer-right {
            float: left;
        }

        /*align footer-right to footer-left*/
        #footer-right ul {
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
        }
    }
```

I have updated the jsfiddle to show the result.  For more on css media queries and examples, refer to [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

Comment: Thank you for your help but I do not see the changes on jsfiidle,

Comment: not sure why the jsfiddle is not updated.  you can copy this part into the css. i've forked the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/oapmuzp6/1/

Comment: you're welcome, care to up vote if you think the answer is useful?